# php mysql want to add 30 days from a feild

Tags: php, mysql

i want to add 30 days from the date $first and the result in $sec to take the data between these days from MySQL

```
$first=05/02/2014
```

result as in

```
$sec= 06/02/2014 in m/d/y format
```

thank you

Comment: Anything you tried yourself? + how is the date stored in mysql? Timestamp, string, ... ?

Comment: date stored i date format

Comment: $sec=strtotime("+60 days", time($first));

Comment: You don't need to do it you can directly achieve this in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
echo $sec=date('m/d/y',strtotime('+30 days', time($first))); //06/04/14
```

Comment: <?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("visa");
$first=$_POST['first'];
$sec=date('m/d/y',strtotime('+10 days', time($first))); 
$r=mysql_query("select * from emp where visaexpdate between '$sec' and '$first'");
if(!$r)
 { echo "retry"; }
else
 {
  while($f=mysql_fetch_array($r))
  {
     echo "<table><tr><td>name</td>"."<td>".$f['empname']."</td></tr></table>";
  }
 }
?>